# What is the scriptural significance of the "solah shringar" in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, marriage, women

Does it have specific religious meaning which can be substantiated by any of the religious texts? Which particular scriptures put forward the idea of "solah shringar" into writing, if any?

Comment: There is no scriptural basis for it, but I read a mythology once which I can't remember now. In another book I read a deep philosophical explanation for them, which also I can't remember. Also this is meant for both men and women and not just for brides.